# How to search a combined cell value with another value (text + text)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, dbo

First time posting and not a SQL expert by any means!

Aim: I want to combine multiple row values (b.[Canvasser Name]) into one combined cell (f.canvassers) and check f.canvasser doesn't contain the same value as aa.[Primary Canvasser]. All of these fields are text.

Problem: I'm encountering a problem where by f.canvassers automatically puts , at the end of the value (how can I correct this?) and also my NOT IN/LIKE statement doesn't pick up on the , either so it's returning values that have the same primary canvasser but also correctly returning values where the primary and proposal canvasser do not match.

```
SELECT aa.[Cons ID], aa.name, aa.[Primary Canvasser], f.[Proposal Import ID], f.Canvassers

FROM [Data_Team].[dbo].[vt_lu_ConstituentBio] as AA
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT a.[Proposal Import ID], a.[Constituent Cons ID],
                             ( SELECT b.[Canvasser Name] + ', ' AS [text()]
                                    FROM [Data_Team].[dbo].[vt_lu_Proposals] B
                                    WHERE a.[Proposal Import ID]=b.[Proposal Import ID]
                                    ORDER BY a.[Proposal Import ID]
                                    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
           ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') [Canvassers]
                 FROM [Data_Team].[dbo].[vt_lu_Proposals] A 
                 where a.[Proposal Active?] = 'active') 
                 as F on f.[Constituent Cons ID]= aa.[Cons ID]

WHERE aa.[Primary Canvasser] NOT IN ('%f.Canvassers%')

ORDER BY aa.[Cons ID]
```

Comment: For advice on how to improve your question see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please, give a sample data and expected result.